# Can you use reflection even if the ReflectionPermission is turned off?

Tags: asp.net, .net, reflection

According to [Godaddy](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1039),

> Applications operating under a Medium trust level have no registry access, no access to the Windows event log, and cannot use ReflectionPermission (**but can use Reflection**).

What can I do, and can I *not* do with ReflectionPermission turned off?

*(I'm using .NET 4)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not need ReflectionPermission to use reflection to discover or invoke types or members that it could have accessed without using reflection.  For example, you can invoke a public method of a public class via reflection even if you do not have ReflectionPermission.